# Understanding an HTTParty configuration

Tags: ruby

In "Learn Ruby the Hard Way", the author advises to go through someones code and try to make sense of it. They also advise that this will be difficult, but to write down questions you are having about the code. The only problem is, I do not know how to get the answers to the questions I have after Googling, so I figure I will try to post them here and see if someone can help me out? Let me know If this is not appropriate and I will try to find another option.

```
require 'httparty'

class BaseWebService
  include HTTParty
  format :json
  base_uri URL_to_mock_services
  default_options.update(verify: false)

  def self.get_data(extension = {}, url = {}, body = {}, query = {})
    url_string = combine_extension_and_url(extension, url)
    do_get = -> (req_url, req_body, req_query) { get(req_url, body: req_body.class == String ? JSON.parse(req_body) : req_body, query: req_query) }
    return_response(url_string, body.to_json, query, &do_get)
  end
```

In the code above the author is setting up a request to 'Mock Services'. The author is using HTTParty to make the requests to the services. I have some questions on the following:

- Why is it that if we require HTTParty in our .rb file that we then
  have to include it within the class? Is it not available by default
  in the entire class?

  - `format :json`: Is this going to format any response we get back from the call as a JSON object?
  - `base_uri`:  Is this automatically called each time we create a new instance of the BaseWebService class? If not, how is it triggered?
  - `default_options`:  I see in the HTTParty documentation that states

    > Returns the value of attribute default_options

    but I am not sure what that means. Nor what it is used for in this class?
  - What does the syntax `do_get = ->` do?
  - In the class method `get_data` the author makes use of `req_url`, `req_body` and `req_query`, but I cannot locate these as variables or methods anywhere in the code base. Do you know how these are being used?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd highly recommend reading other tutorials (in addition to the one you're reading) if you're being thrown to the wolves. Exploring other code is great but you need some basics, which are covered in other tutorials, and which you're asking about. SO isn't a "write a tutorial for me site" so [we expect you to research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593). Once you've exhausted the tutorials and the internet, then it'd be more appropriate to ask. "[ask]" is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're my favorite golfer so I'm going to help you out here...

> Why is it that if we require HTTParty in our .rb file that we then have to include it within the class? Is it not available by default in the entire class?

The `require` keyword is Ruby's way of looking for a file with that name and loading it.

Once required, you now have the ability to access the classes and modules from that file/files, for example, HTTParty.

`include` does something very different here.  You can see [in HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L19) that it is actually a module and when you `include 'AModule'` on a class (`BaseWebService` in your code) you're giving instances of your class access to that module's methods.  That means a method the `HTTParty` module implements, such as `get`, is now available in your `BaseWebService` class via `BaseWebService.new.get`.

> format :json, is this going to format any response we get back from the call as a JSON object?

He's simply overriding the class method `format` (see [HTTParty line #50](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L50)).

> base_uri - Is this automatically called each time we create a new instance of the BaseWebService class? If not, how is it triggered?
>   default_options - I see in the HTTParty docs this states Returns the value of attribute default_options, but I am not sure what that means. Nor what it is used for in this class?

When you call most HTTParty methods, it will look to see if a `base_uri` is set up, and since you're overriding it in your class, it will use that value.

> What does the syntax do_get = -> do?

`do_get = ->` is an assignment, where a new variable `do_get` is assigned a `lambda`.  `->` is short hand for a lambda.

> In the class method get_data the author makes use of the following (req_url, req_body, req_query), but I cannot locate these as variables or methods anywhere in the code base? Do you know how these are being used?

Those variables are assigned values when the block is `yielded` to.

Comment: Thanks x100 for this answer Anthony. I appreciate you breaking everything down so specifically. It makes much more sense now. When I win the FedEx cup this year, you will get a mention in my press conference.